# how to filter arrays with local storage objects in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, local-storage, onsen-ui

I am new to Angularjs and am trying to build a news app in phonegap. In this app, a user can select categories such as sports, tech, etc (which are saved in local storage) and only news articles with those categories are displayed to the user. However, when a user selects the categories, they are being saved but I am lost as to how to compare those categories with the category from the news article(the news articles are being pulled from a external website in JSON format which has category along with title and description). Below is the code that I have so far. Any help can be greatly appreciated.

html code:

```
 <div ng-repeat="new in news | limitTo: paginationLimit()">
 <img ng-src="{{new.picture}}"alt="{{new.title}}" />
 <b class="title">{{new.title}}</b>
 <span class="catsource">{{new.category + ' | ' + new.source}}</span>
 <p ng-model="letterLimit">{{new.body | limitTo:letterLimit  }}...</p>
```

angularjs code:

```
 app.controller('NewsController', function($scope, $http, NewsData) {
 $scope.news = [];
 var getData = function ($done) {
 $http({method: 'GET', url: NewsData.url}).
 success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
 if ($done) { $done(); }
 $scope.news = data.result;
 $scope.letterLimit = NewsData.letterLimit; }); } };
```

The newsdata.url here is from data.js file which has all the data including url of the external website.

The code below is for categories controller where the categories selected are saved.

```
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, Data, localStorageService) {

    $scope.items = Data.items;

    if (localStorageService.get('items')) {
        $scope.items = localStorageService.get('items');
    }

    $scope.SaveCategories = function () {
    localStorageService.clearAll();
    localStorageService.add('items',$scope.items);

    } )};
```

I am thinking maybe I can use a filter to filter out the selected categories but it did not work when I tried to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand what you want to achieve correctly is that you want to filter the news you receive as json to only include the categories the user has selected?

If so, do something like this:
add this to your NewsController

```
var filterNews = function(news) {
    var k = news && news.length ? news.length : 0;
    var i = 0;
    var filters = localStorageService.get('items') || null;
    var filteredNews = [];

    if(!filters) {
       return news;
    }
    //if filters is an array.
    for(;i<k;i++) {
        if(filters.indexOf(news[i].category) !== -1) {
            filteredNews.push(news[i]);
        }
   }
   //If filters is an object.
    for(;i<k;i++) {
        if(filters[news[i].category]) {
            filteredNews.push(news[i]);
        }
   }

   return filteredNews;
};
```

then call the function when you set this:

```
 $scope.news = data.result;
```

to

```
$scope.news = filterNews(data.result);
```

and also note that you have to import the localStorageService to your NewsController as well

The best case would be if you could specify the categories in the request you make to return only the categories you want

Comment: Thank you Joonas. I tried your code but when I go to the news page after selecting the categories, it is not displaying anything. I tried without selecting any categories, but again it is not showing anything. So I tried to see if the local storage is being accessed, so I put a window.alert after the    var filters = localstorageservice.get('items') || null; and the alert says [object object] [object object] and so on. I am not sure if I am storing the checkbox values correctly.

Comment: It seems you are storing the objects directly to localStorage. You need to call JSON.stringify(objectToSave) before saving them, so that they are stored as string representations of the objects. Then when you fetch them, you need to call JSON.parse(fetchedValue) to turn them into objects again

Comment: I did it and the reason was because both the category title and its value (true or false) is being saved in the localstorage and we are comparing just the category title with both title as well as it's value. Is there any way we can get just the titles from local storage which are only true? or is it possible to compare title and value (true) with title and value from local storage?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand what you mean by that but if you mean that the categories are held in an object and not an array, I'll edit my original post to reflect that.